# Setting \linespread for a document, but not effect matrices

Tags: tex-general

Here's my page, using a `\linespread` of 2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    margin=20mm,
}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Mt}[1]{\bm{\mathrm{#1}}}
\linespread{2}
\begin{document}
\section*{Question 1}
We input the coefficients into coefficient matrix $\Mt{A}$, the unknowns into vector $\Mt{x}$ and the right hand sides into vector $\Mt{b}$
\begin{align*}
\Mt{A}=
\begin{pmatrix}
    2&-1&0\\
    -2&2&5\\
    4&-4&-3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

For the matrix though, it produces a spread out matrix

[image: Matrix Spread out]

Is it possible to set the line spread out globally, but not for matrices or arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter `\arraystretch` is what you need to cope with: it is a further multiplier for the interline space in arrays and tabular material in general.

If you set it to the reciprocal of the spread factor, you're done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    margin=20mm,
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm} % load after amsmath

%\newcommand{\Mt}[1]{\bm{\mathrm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Mt}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} % much simpler!

\linespread{2}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5} % the reciprocal of 2

\begin{document}

\section*{Question 1}

We input the coefficients into coefficient matrix $\Mt{A}$, the unknowns into
vector $\Mt{x}$ and the right hand sides into vector $\Mt{b}$
\begin{equation*}
\Mt{A}=
\begin{pmatrix}
    2&-1&0\\
    -2&2&5\\
    4&-4&-3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I've made also a couple of fixes with comments; also, don't use `align` as a substitute for `equation` when a single equation is displayed.

[image]